# AJAX with Servlets using JQuery and JSON does not populate the drop down list

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I am using AJAX with Servlet that uses JQuery and JSON.But somehow it is not working well.

The user select an option from the "field" drop down list, the option id's is being sent to the servlet that fetches the desired data from a database and send it back to the jsp page. The AJAX function should populate the "sub" drop down list but it doesn't.

I wrote a simple System.out.println... in my servlet and i found that the servlet is getting called from my JSP using the Ajax code and builds the desired JSONObject, but the data that the servlet sends in response does not populate the drop down list (id="sub").

**jsp:**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
  content="text/html; charset=windows-1255">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#fields').change(function(event){
    var $f = $('option:selected').val();
    $.get('subfields.do',{field:$f}, function(responseJson){
        var $sub = $('#sub');
        $sub.find('option').remove();
        $.each(responseJson, function(key, value){
        $('<option>').val(key).text(value).appendTo($sub);   
        });
    });
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container2">
        <div id="col1">
            <select id="fields">
                <c:forEach var="field" items="${info.fields}">
                    <option value="${field.key}">${field.value}</option>
                </c:forEach>
            </select> 
            <select id="sub">
                <option>Select Field</option>
            </select>
       </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Web.xml:**

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>subfields</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.Subfields</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>subfields</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/subfields.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**Servlet:**

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {       
    request.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    String field = request.getParameter("field");
    System.out.println("field is " + field);
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject ob = new JSONObject();
    try {
        conn = DBConnection.getConnection();
        st = conn.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT ID, SUBDISCIPLINE_NAME FROM SUBDISCIPLINE WHERE DISCIPLINE_ID =" + field);
        while(rs.next()){
            try {
                ob = new JSONObject();
                ob.put("id", rs.getInt(1));
                ob.put("name", rs.getString(2));
                System.out.println("ob is " + ob);
                arr.put(ob.toString());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }       
        }
        out.print(arr);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
            try {
                if(conn!=null) conn.close();
                if(st!=null) st.close();
                if(rs!=null) rs.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

}
```

What am i doing wrong?